# display 2 div's according to select options using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to display div's according to the select option in the HTML using jquery. this works fine.

however, I need to know how I can display both of them if the option `front an back` is selected?

here is my current code:

JS:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#Field169').change(function(){
            $('.myDivs').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });

</script>
```

html:

```
<div class="myDivs" id="Front" align="center>Front</div>

<div class="myDivs" id="Back" align="center>Back</div>


<select id="Field169">
<option value="WHAT DO I NEED HERE??">Front and Back</option>
    <option value="Front">Front Only</option>
    <option value="Back">Back Only</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leave the value blank and then change your jquery:

```
    $('#Field169').change(function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        if (selectedValue === '') {
            $('.myDivs').show();
        } else {
            $('.myDivs').hide();
            $('#' + selectedValue).show();
        }
    });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AG8KW/1/)

Comment: Excellent. just what I was looking for. SIMPLE, QUICK and PERFECT. I will select this as the answer. appreciate it mate

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="Front, #Back">Front and Back</option>
```

Comment: that didn't do anything though!

Comment: I think it should, although I would probably move the `#` from being hard-coded in the selector to the option value so that it looks like `#Front, #Back`.  Then it would be just like what I proposed, but using IDs rather than classes.  Then the selector could be more generic rather than always assuming it was going to be an ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it if you're referencing by IDs, but if you gave them classes with those same names instead, and your option values looked like `.front` and `.back` then your combined option could have the value `value=".front, .back"` and the selector would get both of them.  You would want to change the function to look like:

```
$($(this).val()).show();
```

rather than selecting by ID

Comment: any chance you could do a quick jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#Field169').change(function(){
 var getvalue=$(this option: selected).text();
 if(getvalue=='Front and Back')
 {
 $('#front').show();
 $('#back').show();
 }
 });
```